# Is there a way to test CSP (Content-Security-Protocols) through browser settings?

Tags: javascript, security, firefox, content-security-policy

Currently, I need to set my CSP to `script-src: 'unsafe-eval'` on firefox due to some eval functions somewhere in my page. I've downloaded the firefox developer and set CSP enabled. But is there a way to see if the function I changed is the root cause of the problem?

For example, it'd be great if I can turn my CSP header through firefox to say `script-src: self;` and then have my site breaking/ receiving CSP errors until I finally fix the root cause of my CSP errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I've downloaded the firefox developer*"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your question, or if you are still facing issues given that you asked this about 9 month ago. But since someone else might have the same question, I would suggest to look into the CSP 'report-only mode', which basically runs the CSP without enforcing it, logging all issues it encounters.

Here's some more detailed info:
[CSP-Report-Only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if the browser will allow you to do that but you can test and get recommendations from the site, https://securityheaders.io/.